# Kubernetes: Unable to configure Nginx Ingress to access an internal service

Tags: docker, kubernetes, nginx-ingress

I am following a tutorial to access a **pod** running inside a Kubernetes **cluster** behind a **service**. This Kubernetes cluster is running on Windows 10 using Desktop Docker (by enabling the Kubernetes option)

I am unable to access it using this https://local.ticket.dev/api/users/currentuser it always says "**Site can't be reached**: local.ticket.dev unexpectedly closed the connection."

I have disabled the redirect but it still redirects **HTTP** to **HTTPs**

```
Request URL: http://local.ticket.dev/api/users/currentuser
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 307 Internal Redirect
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin

Location: https://local.ticket.dev/api/users/currentuser
Non-Authoritative-Reason: HSTS
```

Here is visually what I want

[image: Kubernetes Nginx Ingress]

**kubectl get ing**

```
NAME              CLASS    HOSTS              ADDRESS   PORTS   AGE
ingress-service   <none>   local.ticket.dev             80      29s
```

**kubectl get services**
Please note it's running on local machine windows 10 with Docker Desktop. and the LoadBalancer **external** IP always remain **pending** even after 6 hours

```
NAME                                       TYPE           CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                      AGE
auth-srv                                   ClusterIP      10.96.254.94     <none>        3000/TCP                     45s
kubernetes                                 ClusterIP      10.96.0.1        <none>        443/TCP                      5h17m
nginx-ingress-1629401528-controller        LoadBalancer   10.110.199.210   <pending>     80:31430/TCP,443:32346/TCP   5h13m
nginx-ingress-1629401528-default-backend   ClusterIP      10.108.79.252    <none>        80/TCP                       5h13m
```

**kubectl get pods**

```
NAME                                                        READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
auth-depl-c98cdf66f-txqxt                                   1/1     Running   0          54s
nginx-ingress-1629401528-controller-569576ddbd-2htxz        1/1     Running   0          5h13m
nginx-ingress-1629401528-default-backend-69c7fc6549-xxf8w   1/1     Running   0          5h13m
```

> **How I configured it is as follows**

**1 - Installation of Nginx by the following command**

```
helm install stable/nginx-ingress --generate-name
```

**2 - Skaffold dev**

```
Listing files to watch...
 - billo/ticket_auth
Generating tags...
 - billo/ticket_auth -> billo/ticket_auth:latest
Some taggers failed. Rerun with -vdebug for errors.
Checking cache...
 - billo/ticket_auth: Found Locally
Starting test...
Tags used in deployment:
 - billo/ticket_auth -> billo/ticket_auth:d869228....
Starting deploy...
 - deployment.apps/auth-depl created
 - service/auth-srv created
 - ingress.networking.k8s.io/ingress-service created
Waiting for deployments to stabilize...
 - deployment/auth-depl is ready.
Deployments stabilized in 2.302 seconds
Waiting for deployments to stabilize...
Deployments stabilized in 6.9904ms
Press Ctrl+C to exit
Watching for changes...
[auth]
[auth] > auth@1.0.0 start
[auth] > ts-node-dev --poll src/index.ts
[auth]
[auth] [INFO] 00:59:23 ts-node-dev ver. 1.1.8 (using ts-node ver. 9.1.1, typescript ver. 4.3.5)
[auth] Auth!!!! listen to 3000 port
```

if I look at the last line it seems that my Auth Pod is running on 3000 port.

**auth-depl.yaml**

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: auth-depl
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: auth
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: auth
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: auth
          image: billo/ticket_auth
          imagePullPolicy: Never
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: auth-srv
spec:
  selector:
    app: auth
  ports:
    - name: auth
      protocol: TCP
      port: 3000
      targetPort: 3000
```

**ingress-srv.yaml**

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-service
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "false"
spec:
  rules:
    - host: local.ticket.dev
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /api/users/?(.*)
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: auth-srv
                port:
                  number: 3000
```

**Configuration in the Host file**

```
# Added by Docker Desktop
127.0.0.1 host.docker.internal
127.0.0.1 gateway.docker.internal
# To allow the same kube context to work on the host and the container:
127.0.0.1 kubernetes.docker.internal
# End of section
127.0.0.1 ingress.local
127.0.0.1 local.ticket.dev
```

Comment: whats output do  ping `local.ticket.dev` and `telnet local.ticket.dev 80`

Comment: as I see you should to access without https, use `http://local.x.x` instead

Comment: it auto redirect to https

Comment: Could you attach the link to your tutorial? Which version of Kubernetes did you use?

Comment: Sorry that the link is not accessible publically but I can share the details you need to find the problem. Kubernetes version is `v1.21.3`

Comment: can you please add the events for the pending service?

Answer (score 0):

First Disable the HTTPS redirect first

```
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "false"
```

add annotation into the ingress

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-service
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "false"
spec:
  rules:
    - host: local.ticket.dev
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /api/users/?(.*)
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: auth-srv
                port:
                  number: 3000
```

Did you get the external IP for Nginx controller svc? it's showing pending as you are on the Local system.

You might also need to add entries into host file

manually adding your ingresses' hostnames to **/etc/hosts**:

```
127.0.0.1     ingress.local
127.0.0.1     local.ticket.dev
OR 

Host IP       local.ticket.dev
```

Comment: Yes already tried with both, `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "false"` and
`nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/force-ssl-redirect: "false"` but no impact. (it still redirect to https)
and, I have already added an entry in the host file.

Comment: hi Harsh what is the significance of `127.0.0.1 ingress.local`